# Clarifying PT symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, parity, time-reversal-symmetry, cpt-symmetry

I understand that if a Hamiltonian remains invariant under the following transformations then it is PT invariant,

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{Parity \; reversal:} \; \; \hat{p} \to -\hat{p} \; \; \mathrm{ and } \; \; \hat{x} \to -\hat{x} \\
\mathrm{Time \; reversal:} \; \; \hat{p} \to -\hat{p}, \; \hat{x} \to \hat{x}, \; \; \mathrm{ and } \; \; i \to -i.
\end{eqnarray}

However, if during parity reversal we change the sign on momentum, and during time reversal, we change it back, what's the use of performing these rotations on $\hat{p}$? Similarly, the momentum operator contains a first space derivative. Does changing $\hat{p} \to -\hat{p}$ imply that we take $\hat{x} \to -\hat{x}$ (or does the effect cancel out when both $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{x}$ are reversed)?

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you are asking here. Of course $PT$ has no effect on ${\hat p}$ but it still affects ${\hat x}$ and in general all of the other operators as well as states in the theory and is therefore still non-trivial.

Comment: @Prahar I was under the impression that only the $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{x}$ operators were involved in the change of variables for the PT symmetry. Is it not the case?

Comment: I mean all other operators that are made out of ${\hat p}$ and ${\hat x}$. For instance, the Hamiltonian, ${\hat H}$.

Comment: @Prahar I see what you mean. But if $\hat{p} = -i \hbar \partial_x$, then for parity reversal $\hat{p}$ is invariant, right? (Because both $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{x}$ change sign). Same for time reversal, but now because we change $i \to -i$. I have the simplest Hamiltonian and it just seems that there's an overkill happening with changing of the variables for all these inversions, especially since $\hat{p}$ is defined in terms of $x$.

Comment: ${\hat p}$ is not generally defined in terms of $x$. It only takes the form of a derivative when acting on position eigenstates, namely wavefunctions. For parity reversal, ${\hat p} \to - {\hat p}$ as you have written in your question. All you need to do is take $x \to - x$ in $- i \hbar \partial_x$ to see this. Under time reversal also ${\hat p} \to - {\hat p}$ since $i \to - i$.

Comment: If you're working in the position basis, then forget about ${\hat x}$ and ${\hat p}$. All you have is the operator $- i \partial_x$ and $x$ itself. Parity reversal is $x \to -x$ and time reversal is $i \to - i$.

Comment: @Prahar I think this answers my question (your last comment), because I am working in a position basis. That's what I've been getting mixed up. If you write this up I'll accept your answer.